Molding above door pulled off by curtain mount
A few years ago I replaced an old curtain rod with a new Kwik-Hang that mounts to the molding instead of the wall (needed the lower height because of the length of the curtain). Today, I went to spackle over the holes from the old curtain rod, and it looks like the Kwik-Hang mount has been pulling the molding away from the wall due to the weight of the curtain. How should I re-attach the molding, and should I re-attach the Kwik-Hang rod differently? Thanks!
Link to photos: https://imgur.com/a/YSjYrus

Most moulding/trim is only attached with the smallest finishing nails required.  Finish nails do not hold wood well(trim very low weight).  Trim is to make stuff look better, not to have stuff hanging from it.  Real nails/screws will work to hold trim on, but look ugly.

Agree with @crip659.  You could try replacing the finish nails with real nails or screws, but if you have any sense of aesthetics, be prepare to need to seal and paint over them.

Thanks for the help! I have a carpenter coming by for a different project, so I'll see what he thinks, but it seems like some wood glue and a few counter-sunk screws is the way to go, then wood-fill and paint over that.
